# Why is this foreign key constraint not working?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm creating a new table who will have relationships with an existing table. The new table has a column `user_id` which references a `userid` column on another table (the ID of a user in the `users` table).

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `ads` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  -- Other columns...
)
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
  ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Adding a referencing column

```
ALTER TABLE `ads` ADD `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL
```

Which references the following column

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  userid INT(11) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
-- Other irrelevant fields...
);
```

And finally my key definition:

```
ALTER TABLE `ads` ADD CONSTRAINT ads_user_id_foreign FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`userid`)
```

But for some reason I still get an error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `ads` add constraint ads_user_id_foreign foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`userid`))
```

**Note:** *I don't believe it's of much relevance, but I'm using Laravel's query builder to create the new table. I'm getting these queries from PHPStorm's **Copy DDL** feature to show you the equivalent "vanilla MySQL query".*

Comment: This is probably a problem with Laravel.  It works fine on SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84ee79.

Comment: That's the generated query Laravel executes. So maybe I'm missing something that's more relevant than I think? I used `php artisan migrate --pretend` to show me the queries it's trying

Comment: . . One possibility is that the columns are actually named the same in both tables (say, `user_id`) but the `alter table` has the misspelling.

Comment: Nope. Triple-checked. Also checked character set and collation and forced those to match, too. Do engines need to match as well?

Comment: Got it. Engine, charset, and collation were wrong. Added my own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out. In my case, I also needed to change the engine, charset, and collation of the `users` table. IT was set to `MyISAM`, `latin1`, and `latin1_swedish_ci`, respectively.

I did say I was using Laravel, so here are the statements I used to fix that:

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci');
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE users ENGINE=InnoDB;');
```

I'll try to leave a generic answer here for those who find this post in the future.

---

## Things to check when foreign keys aren't working:

#### 1. Make sure that the columns are setup identically

I use an IDE (PHPStorm) that allows me to get some DDL from existing tables. I paste that somewhere and find the columns in question to see if they're defined correctly.

#### 2. Check table status for inconsistencies

You can check all tables' statuses with [`SHOW TABLE STATUS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html). You'll get a result that looks like this (obviously this depends on your IDE):

[image]

Make sure that `engine` and `collation` match in both tables

• If you notice that your `engine` is wrong (it should be **InnoDB**), you can fix it with

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

• If you notice that your `collation` is wrong, you can fix it with

```
alter table <table_name> convert to character set <CHARSET> collate <COLLATION>;
```

*(where a charset might be `utf8` and a collation might be `utf8_unicode_ci`)*